# Comprobar si Una CONSTRAINT UNIQUE ya existe en una tabla? Visual Basic .NET Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Estoy en Visual Basic tratando de hacer un programa para manejar una base de datos, bien tengo la siguiente sentencia SQL en el programa para añadir UNIQUE a dos campos de una tabla:

```
"ALTER TABLE RESEARCHERS ADD CONSTRAINT RESEARCHERS UNIQUE (resEmail, 
resPhoneNumber);"
```

Pero quiero hacer que antes de añadirla compruebe si ya existe, puesto que sino el programa da un error.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer una consulta previa, o bien hacer el intento de `INSERT` (que asumo es lo que quieres hacer) y comprobar si hay error:

```
Try
    ; Tu instrucción a la BD (ExecuteNonQuery())
Catch ex As SqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, _
        "Error en la base de datos", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
End Try
```

Te recomiendo esto ya que evitas una consulta adicional a la base de datos en caso que todo esté bien, y si sucede un error puedes informar fácilmente al usuario sobre ello.